# Python, Get element from list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists with data like credit pays schedule:

```
[ [pay_number, pay_date, pay_amount], [pay_number, pay_date, pay_amount], e.t.c ]
```

how can I get next pay_date from it ?

Comment: I meant next pay_date related to current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the list:

```
thelist = [ [pay_number, pay_date, pay_amount], [pay_number, pay_date, pay_amount], ... ]

for sub_list in thelist:
    current_pay_date = sub_list[1]
    # do something with current_pay_date
```

If you want to access the next `pay_date`:

```
for i in range(len(thelist)):
    sub_list = thelist[i]
    current_pay_date = sub_list[1]
    next_sub_list = thelist[i+1]
    next_pay_date = next_sub_list[1]
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: for sub_list in thelist :
        current_pay_date = sub_list[1]
        if current_pay_date > datetime.date.today() :
            return sub_list
that what I need. Thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of `range(len(thelist))`, you could just use `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`min`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function to get the element from your list which is the closest to today by using a custom `key` function:

```
>>> items = [[1, datetime.date(2014, 2, 28), 1], [2, datetime.date(2014, 2, 7), 2], [3, datetime.date(2014, 2, 14), 3]]
>>> min(items, key=lambda x: x[1] - datetime.date.today())
[2, datetime.date(2014, 2, 7), 2]
```

Comment: >>> items = [[1, datetime.date(2014, 1, 28), 1], [2, datetime.date(2014, 2, 13), 2], [3, datetime.date(2014, 2, 14), 3]]
>>> min(items, key=lambda x: x[1] - datetime.date.today())
>>> [1, datetime.date(2014, 1, 28), 1]

but it's in past